# Does Python really create all bound method for every new instance?

Tags: java, python, oop, methods

I am reading about classes in Python (3.4) and from what I understand it seems that every new object has its own bound methods instances.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        print(self.name)

a = A('One')
b = A('Two')

print(a.foo ==  b.foo)
```

The output of this is `False`.

This seems to me as a waste of memory. I thought that internally `a.foo` and `b.foo` would point somehow internally to one function in memory: `A.foo` where `self` as the class instance will be passed.

I assume this maybe cannot be implemented easily in the language.

Does each new instance contain also new instances of its bound methods?

If so, does not this hurt the performance or make case for creating new objects more cautiously than in other languages where methods are "shared" among objects like in Java?

Comment: Can you link to something you read that makes you think that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `X().f == X.f` will result in `False` (where f is an instace method). This is enough to make one think like that.

Comment: Each bound method, though, references the same underlying function. The memory overhead for the wrappers is minimal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Methods are bound *on demand*, each time you access one.

Accessing the name of a function invokes the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), which on function objects returns a bound method.

A bound method is a thin wrapper around a function object; it stores a reference to the original function and to the instance. When calling a method object, it in turn passes the call to the function, with instance inserted as a first argument.

Methods are not created when the instance is created, so there is no extra memory required a-priori.

You can re-create the steps manually:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def foo(self):
...         print(self.name)
... 
>>> a = A('One')
>>> a.foo
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x100a27978>>
>>> a.foo.__self__
<__main__.A object at 0x100a27978>
>>> a.foo.__func__
<function A.foo at 0x100a22598>
>>> A.__dict__['foo']
<function A.foo at 0x100a22598>
>>> A.__dict__['foo'].__get__(a, A)
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x100a27978>>
>>> A.__dict__['foo'].__get__(a, A)()
One
```

It is only the method object that is recreated each time; the underlying function remains stable:

```
>>> a.foo is a.foo
False
>>> b = A('Two')
>>> b.foo is a.foo
False
>>> b.foo.__func__ is a.foo.__func__
True
```

This architecture also makes [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod), and [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) objects work. You can create your own descriptors, creating a whole host of interesting binding behaviours.

Comment: It's your answer here, too, so you get the rep you clearly don't need more of either way ;o)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: hah, but this one is already accepted! :-P I didn't fully re-read the question here; in retrospect both question and answer are a perfect duplicate. I had the impression there was more to explain on the other post.

Answer (score 3):

Demystifying checker I made shows, functions are saved inside the main class `A` dictionary and shared among instances. But then the last couple lines shows once we bound the methods they are on unique memory address.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def foo(self):
        print(self.name)

a = A('One')
b = A('Two')

d=a.__dict__
D=A.__dict__
print('dict a:', d)
print('dict A:', D)

print(D['foo']) #<function A.foo at 0x000001AF4258CC80>
# both next __func__ point to the parent dict
print(a.foo.__func__) #<function A.foo at 0x000001AF4258CC80>
print(b.foo.__func__) #<function A.foo at 0x000001AF4258CC80>

print(a.foo)
print(b.foo)
#already bound on unique address
print(a.foo==b.foo)
```

---

The full output:

```
dict a: {'name': 'One'}
dict A: {'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x000001AF425D3730>, 'foo': <function A.foo at 0x000001AF425D3620>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
<function A.foo at 0x000001AF425D3620>
<function A.foo at 0x000001AF425D3620>
<function A.foo at 0x000001AF425D3620>
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x000001AF425E21D0>>
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x000001AF42375C50>>
False
```