# Strange behavior passing bound method to function

Tags: python, methods, variable-assignment, argument-passing

I believe that `func(obj.attr)` and `tmp = obj.attr; func(tmp)` should be completely indistinguishable. However, the following code

```
class Cls(object):
    #@staticmethod
    def f(self):
        pass

def who(obj):
    print(id(obj) % 1000, end=' ')

obj = Cls()

n = 10

for i in range(n):
    who(obj.f)

print('\n')

for i in range(n):
    tmp = obj.f
    who(tmp)
```

produces

```
736 736 736 736 736 736 736 736 736 736 

736 216 736 216 736 216 736 216 736 216
```

We can see that the second for loop produces a interesting pattern, while the first one does not. It seems that assigning a bound method would alter the bound method itself, but why passing it to a function wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python creates a *new* bound method object every time you access `f` (see [Does Python really create all bound method for every new instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378912/does-python-really-create-all-bound-method-for-every-new-instance)).

In the first loop:

- At the first iteration:

  - `obj.f` creates the bound method object.
  - `who` prints the id
  - There are no more references to the bound method object, hence it is deallocated immediately by the interpreter
- At the following iteration:

  - `obj.f` creates a new bound method object. *The intrepreter reuses the memory freed at the iteration before*.
  - `who` prints the id which *happen* to match the previous id
  - Again the object is deallocated

In the second loop:

- At the first iteration

  - `obj.f` creates a new bound method object
  - It is assigned to `tmp` (and thus it has a reference now)
  - `who` prints the id
  - **No deallocation is performed**. The `tmp` variable keeps the object alive
- At the following iteration

  - `obj.f` creates a new bound method object. **It cannot reuse the old address because that object is still alive.**
  - It is assigned to `tmp`. **Now the old value of `tmp` has no more references and thus is deallocated.**
  - `who` prints the id, **which is a new one**.
  - Again no deallocation occurs
- At the following iteration

  - `obj.f` creates a new bound method object. Now the old-old address is again available and the interpreter decides to reuse it.
  - It is assigned to `tmp`. **Now the old value of `tmp` has no more references and thus is deallocated.**
  - `who` prints the id, **which is a old-old one**
  - Again no deallocation occurs

and so a loop is created that alternates between the two addresses.

By using more variables you can create longer cycles:

```
>>> tmp1 = obj.f
>>> tmp2 = tmp3 = tmp4 = tmp5 = None
>>> for i in range(20):
...     tmp5 = tmp4
...     tmp4 = tmp3
...     tmp3 = tmp2
...     tmp2 = tmp1
...     tmp1 = obj.f
...     who(tmp1)
... 
864 896 560 280 288 864 896 560 280 288 864 896 560 280 288 864 896 560 280 288
```

Or, as mentioned by Reblochon Masque in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32287872/510937), using `del` you can avoid the behaviour:

```
>>> for i in range(20):
...     tmp = obj.f
...     who(tmp)
...     del tmp   # forget the name
... 
688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688 688
```

Note that this is due to implementation details of CPython. In Jython or other python implementations without reference counting both loops will probably behave pretty much in the same way: showing ten different ids.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a complement to Bakuriu' answer:

If you delete temp before continuing the iteration, you get the same result as in case 1:

```
(...)
for i in range(n):
    tmp = obj.f
    who(tmp)
    del(tmp)
```

produces:

```
496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496 

496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496 496
```

*Of course, the actual number will reflect what state the system used was in at runtime.*