# Python and C# clarification on how functions are used by objects of a class and represented in memory

Tags: python, c#, function, class, inheritance

Well, this is probably the weirdest behaviour I've come accross in Python.
Consider the following code:

```
class wow:
    var = 90

    def __init__(self):


        self.wow = 30

    def great(self):
        self.eme = 90
        print('wow')


var = wow()
varss = wow()
varsss = wow()



print(id(var.great))
print(id(varss.great))
print(id(varsss.great))
print(var.great is varsss.great)
```

**Output**:

```
1861171310144
1861171310080
1861171310144
False
```

Why, everytime I create a new object from the same class, is there everytime a new function created , and why do the memory addresses of the first one and third one match, but not the second one (nor `id(wow.great)`).
And why when I compare the two with the same memory addresses does it return false?

Also another question, a new object gets created from the **wow class**, do all the methods of the **wow class** actually get added to that object, or does the object kind of call the method from the class whenever its needed. I ask this question because I can't see the methods of the **wow class when I do var.**dict****?

Also, when I create the three different instances, will each of those instances actually have its own functions, or will the functions be made availlable by the **wow class** and all instances can just access the same functions whenever they want so the functions don't need to be copied in memory 3 times?

Lastly, I'd like to know if this is actually the same case for C#, would each instance have its own functions (non static) or will there only be one of the functions that each instance can access?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, `vars` is a built-in function so it's better not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: I can't reproduce your first question about the id's, they are all the same.

Comment: This is also 4 complete questions in 1; this question needs more focus.

Comment: In Python a function is a complete object, in C# they are not (there are implicit ways of creating function like objects such as `Action`, but those are a separate thing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python really create all bound method for every new instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378912/does-python-really-create-all-bound-method-for-every-new-instance)

Answer (score 0):

The post linked by SargeATM in the comments ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378912/does-python-really-create-all-bound-method-for-every-new-instance)) actually explains a lot about what is going on. Be sure to check it out ;).  Every time you access a method on an instance, a bound method object is created. You can think of this as a separate object which works roughly in the following way:

```
class BoundMethod:

    def __init__(self, instance, method):
        self.instance = instance
        self.method = method

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.method(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

So, everytime you access `var.great`, `varss.great`, or `varsss.great`, a new bound method object is generated.

There is no clear for the memory addresses you are observing. When you execute `print(id(var.great))`, a bound method object is created with reference count equal to 1, its `id` is printed, and the reference count is decreased. The bound method object will then be de-allocated. The behaviour you are observing is most likely a combination of the python memory management implementation, and possibly some randomness. Personally, when I run your code, all memory addresses are equal -- which means that the same memory gets used everyime.

However, when you execute `print(var.great is varsss.great)`, two separate bound method objects are created, with different memory addresses (because obviously, the same memory cannot be used now). To observe this more clearly, let's rewrite the code:

```
>>> x = var.great
>>> y = varsss.great
>>> print(id(x))
3018906862144
>>> print(id(y))
3018906862272
>>> print(x is y)
False
```

So, `print(var.great is varsss.great)` does not compare objects with the same memory address. The only reason it looked like that is that in your preceding `print` calls, the same memory happened to be used when allocating the bound method object.

---

Methods are stored on the class object. Method calls in Python, such as `var.great()`, are essentially equivalent to `type(var).great(var)`, although this is achieved by first creating the bound method object, which would roughly be equivalent to `bound_method = BoundMethod(var, type(var).great)`.

You can also assign methods/functions as attribute to instances directly, but then they do not behave as normal methods (i.e. no bound method object is created. Hence, the function will not be called with `self` as an argument). This behaviour can be observed using the following code:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.amazing = lambda *args: args 

x = X()
print(x.amazing())
```

(the output of this code is `()`)